# Why am I getting redefinition; different basic types?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why am I getting an error when I try this in Visual C++?

```
struct S { };
typedef S *S;
```

Doesn't C++ [let you `typedef` a name that was previously only declared as a `class` or `struct`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612476/541686)?
Or am I misunderstanding what's going on?

Comment: This would be allowed in C, but not in C++. In C++, `struct S{...};` is roughly equivalent to `typedef struct S{...} S;` in C (i.e., afterwards, you can define an instance of `S` with just `S x;`, without requiring `struct S x;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does allow you to typedef an existing class name, but only in a very restricted way. Once you declared your `struct S` you can do

```
typedef struct S S;
```

but you cannot do

```
typedef struct S *S; // ERROR
```

or

```
typedef int S; // ERROR
```

In the first case the fact that you are redefining `S` as a *pointer* is what breaks it.

The language specification says in 7.1.3/2

> In a given non-class scope, a typedef specifier can be used to
>   redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to the
>   type to which it already refers.

"Already refers" is the key part. In simple words, you can redefine a class name to stand for *the same* class type, but not for a *pointer* to the class type or anything else.

---

The aforementioned part of C++ standard is also what allows you to write repetitive typedefs like

```
typedef int T;
typedef int T;
typedef int T;
```

which would be illegal in C.

Comment: Ohh, so all it allows is a redundant declaration... interesting, thanks. +1

Comment: @Mehrdad Note that repeating the same typedef is allowed in C2011 by 6.7 (3): "a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that type is not a variably modified type;" (with the exception of variably modified types).

Answer (score 1):

This would be okay in C because struct names do not clash with type names - the struct name would be `struct S` and the type name would be just `S`. However, in C++ all names are considered to come from the same pool of names, so the two names in your example will clash.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define S (the typedef) which clashes with "S" (the struct name).